Upper Bound on $\mathbb E[\sqrt{X}]$ with $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{n})$ that is not Jensen
Let $X_n\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{n})$ a random variable with binomial distribution. We then have $\mathbb E[X_n]=1$. My goal is to find a cosntant $0< c< 1$, s.t.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E[\sqrt{X_n}] \leq c.
\end{equation}
for all $n\geq2$. Jensen's inequality is not sufficient for this.
Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121411/expectation-of-square-root-of-binomial-r-v
The post above doesn't really discuss a "better" upper bound. Or is there even one? Maybe I don't fully understand the post on Math Overflow.
Any help is appreciated.

for $n\geq 2$ an upper bound could be $c=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)$ :-)

For $n\ge 1$ the least upper bound is $1$, when $n=1$.  $\mathbb E[\sqrt X]$ is a decreasing function of $n$. Empirically, $0.77319$ seems to be a lower bound equal to $\mathbb E[\sqrt Y]$ for a Poisson distribution with parameter $1$.

$X_n\sim Bi(n,1.n)$ converges to $Poi(1)$ in distribution. By uniform integrability $E[\sqrt{X_n}]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}E[\sqrt{X}]$ where $X\sim Poi(1)$. There should be ample work on fractional moments of the Poisson distribution. A numerical calculation yields $E[\sqrt{X}]\approx 0.773193$.

We need to clarify whether we would like to compute a universal constant for all $n$ (as Henry did), or we need a bound that vary depends on $n$ - $c_n$, or just the limiting value when $n$ is large (a "closed-form" for the limiting value found by Henry)

@Mittens https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285586/fractional-moments-of-poisson-distribution discusses fractional moments of the Poisson distribution.

A Taylor expansion for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ gives $f(x)=f(1) + f'(1)(x-1) + \frac{f''(c)}{2}(x-1)^2$ for some $c$ that lies in between $x$ and $1$. Since $0\leq X\leq n$ we get $f''(c)=-(1/4)c^{-3/2}\leq -(1/4)n^{-3/2}$ and  \begin{align} &\sqrt{X}\leq 1 + (1/2)(X-1) -\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}(X-1)^2 \ &\implies E[\sqrt{X}] \leq 1 + 0 - \frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}np(1-p) = 1 - \frac{(1-1/n)}{8n^{3/2}}\end{align}

@Michael: This is a great approach. Is there a clever way to use Taylor to find an upper bound that does not converge to $1$? As already established the limit is below $0.8$. Maybe through choosing a different expansion point?

Perhaps by using a conditional expectation given, say, $X\leq 2$ and $X>2$. The reason this may be good is that the $c$ value can be bounded by $2$ (when conditioning on the first case) rather than $n$. Of course, when $n=1$ the answer is exactly $1$, so you can’t get an answer better than $1$ if you want it to be independent of $n$ but also hold for all $n$.

Suppose $X_n\sim \operatorname{Binom}(n,\frac1n)$. It is easy to see that $X_n\Longrightarrow\operatorname{Poi}(1)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$; furthermore, by uniform integrability, $\mathbb{E}[X^{1/2}_n]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X^{1/2}]\approx 0.773193\ldots$,  where $X\sim\operatorname{Poi}(1)$. Thus, for all $n$ sufficiently large $\mathbb{E}[X^{1/2}_n]\leq 0.8$.
One can also obtain an explicit form of the rational moments in terms of the Laplace transform of the $\operatorname{Binom}(n,\frac1n)$ measure  as follows (see here)
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^{1/2}_n]=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac12)}\int^\infty_0\big(1-\frac{1-e^{-\theta}}{n}\big)^{n-1}e^{-\theta}\theta^{-1/2}\,d\theta
\end{align}
For $0<a<1$ fixed, define $g(x)=\Big(1-\frac{a}{x+1}\Big)^x$ on $x\ge0$. I leave it to the OP to check that $g$ is monotone decreasing on the interval $[0,\infty)$ (check that $g’(x)<0$ on $(0,\infty)$). From this, it follows that for $m\geq2$
$$0.773193\ldots=E[X^{1/2}]=\lim_n E[X^{1/2}_n]\leq E[X^{1/2}_m]\leq  E[X^{1/2}_2]=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}\approx 0.8535534\ldots$$
